# HTML lists in iOS using native functionality

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uikit, core-text

Is it possible to create HTML lists such as ordered and unordered lists without using UIWebView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `UIWebView` to display/interpret html, unless of course you want to write your own implementation to parse html and display it (but why would you?). If on the other hand you are just trying to display lists without needing html, you can use a `UITableView`.